# How to use double subscript in latex?

Tags: math-mode

i try to write this `$k_{a}^(k)_{kk}$`he is not correct i ty many solution please help me  and i want this for output [image]

Comment: `$ka^{(k)}_{kk}$` ? Or `$k^{(k)}_{a_{kk}}$` ? In your image `$a$` seems not a subscript...

Answer (score 5):

From the image, there don't seem to be two subscripts, rather `k a_{kk}^{(k)} = 0` produces

[image]

In case you wanted more subscripts, you could use `k_{a_{kk}^{(k)}} = 0`, note the double brackets, those are really important. The result is as follows

[image]